# What does the 0 in "{0:MM dd yyyy}" do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I'm new to the C#/MVC world. I spend a lot of time today figuring out how to display a DateTimeOffset object in the format i want. Finally got it working this way.

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeliveryDate,"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", 
                     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

But I still don't understand the importance of '0' in the format string. the page breaks if i replace the 0 with any other number or totally remove it. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: 0 will be replace by datevalue in the model.DeliveryDate in this format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: not working for to date

Answer (score 4):

From [String.Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

The {0} in the format string is a format item. 0 is the index of the object whose string value will be inserted at that position. (Indexes start at 0.) If the object to be inserted is not a string, its ToString method is called to convert it to one before inserting it in the result string.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Make sense to me now. I was thinking that number could be used to offset the date by #of days or something. Appreciate your responses. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That's a format string with parameters (like used in e.g. Console.WriteLine, or string.Format). The `{0}` would be the placeholder for the first argument, and `{0:mm/dd/yyyy}` is simply a format string to convert the first argument to a string.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) you can pass the space for arguments like `{0}`, `{1}`, etc which is the indexes you pass as arguments for the method. It is the same for asp.net razor helpers.

You also can provide the format after the index separating by `:`, for sample: `{0:0.00}` as format for a number with 2 decimals places or `{1:dd/MM/yyyy}` for dates etc.

### String Interpolation

There is a new way to implement it using the `String Interpolation`. Basically, you can concat the values on your string without generating new strings. For sample:

```
var i = 18;
var s = $"You are {age} years old.";
```

Since you start the string with `$`, you can pass arguments between `{` and `}`. You also can use the same formats to format your data as you use on `string.Format`. For sample:

```
var today = $"Today is {DateTime.Now:D}";

var date = DateTime.Now.Add(1);
var tommorrow = $"Tommorrow is {date:dd/MM/yyyy}";
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for `String.Format()`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

In a nutshell, when the model is rendered to HTML text, the `DeliveryDate` object value will be passed to `String.Format()`, where `{0}` indicates the index of the first value in an array of values being passed to `Format()`. So `{0:MM/dd/yyyy}` just means to format the first value in the array using date components.  Basically, it will do something like this internally:

```
String s = SomeValueArray[0].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

0 is a placeholder for your argument / property (in this case) `DeliveryDate`.. Similar to `String.Format` examples... so when your View is rendered.. the 0 will be replaced with whatever value that `DeliveryDate` is holding in the format *MM/dd/yyyy*